# Swift and Firebase - Receiving image from the user then uploading it to firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimagepickercontroller

I want the user to upload an image from the photos library along with more input so I can write it to my database.
I made an object with the received data from the user and I uploaded it (using ".child()") to firebase realtime database, but then I had to add the photo to the object so I used the UIImagePicker to upload the photo then I got stuck.
my problem is that i don't know what type of info I should get from the image so I can add it to the object.
I'm not sure if using an object is the right choice but since the data I’m adding is related to a specific item I thought it would be suitable.

// The object

```
 let object: [String : Any] = ["areaname": areaName! as Any ,"spotNo": spotNo, "loactionLat": areaLat, "locationLong": areaLong]
    database.child("Areas").child("Area_\(Int.random(in: 0..<100))" ).setValue(object)

@IBAction func chooseImageButton() {
    print("Add image button was pressed")
    let vc = UIImagePickerController()
    vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.allowsEditing = true
    present(vc, animated: true)
 
}


extension AddAreaViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediawithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    print("\(info)")
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage {
    }
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5afj.jpg)

Comment: If you're trying to store an image, you should likely be using Firebase Storage instead and then saving a reference to it in your database.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is saving the image using FirebaseStorage. And turn the image url to string write into database. When you need loading image. You can search by that urlstring.

Comment: how can i get the url as a string? and send it to the other function that fills the database object ?

Comment: Is simple to get URL and type casting.`let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL``let imageURL: String = url.path`. If you want send it to another function. You can take a look the 
 document about Swift function's values and return .

Answer (score 0):

I think @Evan Lu is correct.
You don't need to store the image on firebase database or realtime databse.
You can store the image on FirebaseStorage and save the url on database.

Comment: This could be added as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: sorry, I can't add a comment on other questions yet. 
because my profile is not enough to leave a comment.